# Return error message from .bat function Groovy

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, groovy

I'm new to Groovy and Java and I want to get an error message from `.bat()` function. Here is my code:

```
 def stdout = script.bat(
   script: "C:/Work/test.cmd",
   returnStdout: true
 )

 script.echo stdout
```

where `script` is `groovy.lang.Script` variable that comes into the constructor with super(script) and my function is called from this class. Don't know exactly how it works but it works and the `test.cmd` is called properly.
But if there is an error (e.g. file is locked and cannot be deleted) I want to receive the error message which contains the file path. As I know we can add 2>&1 to script part like this:

```
def stdout = script.bat(
   script: "C:/Work/test.cmd 2>&1",
   returnStdout: true
)

script.echo stdout
```

to route an error message to the main output. But if there is an error in the script then it comes out with result != 0 and .bat function throws an exception and doesn't assign a value to `stdout` variable. Moreover there is `returnStatus` argument and if we set it to true then `.bat()` doesn't throw an exception if there is an error in the script but there is only status code in `stdout` even with `returnStdout` in true. So I would like to know if there is a way to get an error message from `.bat()` function

Comment: Does the batch file generate the error? if it does, are exit codes defined by errorlevel in the batch file?

Comment: @Gerhard as I understand yes, the batch file generates the error when it tries to remove a locked file. The second question can't fully understand but if I use `returnStatus` parameter the `.bat()` returns 1. I don't have access to the batch file and can't view or edit it (till real necessity appears)

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at the help information for the `exit` command, i.e. Open a Command Prompt, type `exit /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key. Then you could use `%ERRORLEVEL%` as the argument to it, at the end of your batch file.

Comment: @Compo but as I mentioned, editing the batch file is almost impossible. It will be the last this I would like to do. But thanks, if there is no way I'll try `exit`

Comment: Currently your code is only determining whether the batch file was successfully executed, not whether the code within it was successful. There has to be a mechanism within the batch file which sends the command output to a file for checking, or as an error/exit code for you to be able to return to the calling command.